# How can I add multiple projects on the same Azure DevOps Board?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have two Projects in one Organization (like in the attached image below).

I would like to see the items from both Projects in the same Azure DevOps Board (dashboard).

Azure DevOps Boards (dashboards) show just the items from the selected Project.

How can I add items (User Stories) from both Projects to the same Azure DevOps Board?

(There is pretty good documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/?view=azure-devops but I did not find the answer)

[image]

Comment: it seems there is not a right solution, I will have to close it

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I am afraid, there is no proper solution at the moment, Azure Boards is a quite new product, I guess we will have a decent way to solve this issue soon

Answer (score 11):

> How I can add multiple projects on the same Azure DevOps Board?

Just as we know, Azure DevOps Board is associated with an Iteration Path(Agile). An iteration path only exists within the context of a Team Project. So, Azure DevOps Board boards by their current implementation live only within a Team Project.

As a workaround, you can try to use the extension [Delivery Plans](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans), with Delivery Plans, you gain tailor-made views across several teams and their development backlogs—stories, features, or epics. You can use these views to drive alignment across teams by overlaying several backlogs onto your delivery schedule:

Check the document [Managing project schedules across teams with Delivery Plans](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/deliveryplans/) for some more details.

BTW, there is a user voice [Single Dashboard for Multiple Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365500/single-dashboard-for-multiple-projects.html), which is on the roadmap, you can vote and track the feedback from this ticket.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that. I think you have to use one team project and several teams. Just create separate teams for each project. Azure DevOps will create an area path for each team. Then each team will use their own backlogs. In the default project team you can select "Include sub areas," and then you will see items for all teams (or projects).
[image]

Additional links:

1. [Add a team, move from one default team to several teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops)
2. [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops)

Comment: This is the way to go. Although it seems most intuitive to have multiple projects, it s not what Microsoft recommends. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#when-to-add-another-project.

Note that you can also assign multiple teams to an area path.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable with some limitations.

- Make sure you have installed plugin, https://github.com/edtro/EdTro.AzureDevOps.Extensions.querybasedboards
- Create a new shared query across projects and teams you want to have on a board. Don't forget to check *Query across projects*
- When you are done, click on "Show as Board"
- Unfortunately, there is only limited settings in UI, but rest of settings is doable using JSON. Go to *Project Settings/Extensions - Query Based Boards,* *select* your *query* and follow instructions as on https://github.com/edtro/EdTro.AzureDevOps.Extensions.querybasedboards/blob/master/public/config.md

Limitations:

- Configuration through manual JSON config
- How to effectively do planning across projects with many backlogs

Answer (score 0):

It is doable with Portfolio++.  It's an Azure DevOps extension.  You can create your custom board from multiple projects as long as they are in the same Azure DevOps organization.